# Why can't get Address from location?

Tags: android

```
if (isOnline()) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(con, Locale.getDefault());
                    p = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                            (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
                    List<Address> add = null;
                    try {
                        add = geocoder.getFromLocation(p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,
                                p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        // e.printStackTrace();
                    }
}
```

Yesterday , I get Address is ok, But today, I can't get address (add=null) .

Comment: plz check [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html) tutorial!!

Comment: Yesterday , I get Address is ok, But today, I can't get address (Internet is activity). Today. Is service of google error?